# I am getting Element not interractable exception

Tags: selenium

```
"public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\agile\\Downloads\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");  
      
       // Instantiate a ChromeDriver class.       
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();  
    driver.navigate().to("https://uat.myatom.app/risksecure/#/auth/login");
```

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

```
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://uat.myatom.app/risksecure/#/auth/login");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/auth/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/auth-login/div/form/div/div[1]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(9000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/auth/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/auth-login/div/form/div/div[1]")).sendKeys("himanshu.chand168@webkul.com");
```

}}"

Comment: On which row do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Use expected conditions. Read more on https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement anyElem= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("anyXPATH")));
    anyElem.click(); // just perform action you need I perforemed a click on element
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to send keyboard inputs to a div tag which is non editable. Send elements to input tag instead:

use this xpath:

```
'/html/body/app-root/auth/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/auth-login/div/form/div/div[1]/input'
```

but using absolute xpath is not recommended use relative xpath:

```
//input[@formcontrolname="username"]
```

also use explict wait :

```
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.get("https://uat.myatom.app/risksecure/#/auth/login");
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@formcontrolname=\"username\"]"))).send_keys("something");
```